# Add label to entire bar within ggplot stacked bar chartr

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have some survey data regarding how much individuals agree/disagree with some statements.  I want to basically make a stacked bar chart from this data, where the bars represent the statements, and the different sections within each bar represent the percentage of responses at each level.

Given the way my data is structured (sample data included below), I can create this type of chart with the follow code:

```
ggplot(data=data, aes(x = items)) +
  geom_bar(aes(fill = answer), position = "fill") +
  coord_flip() +
  guides(fill = guide_legend(reverse = TRUE))
```

I would like to go one step further with this chart, and include the percentage of people that either agree or strongly agree with each of the statements as a label on each bar.  I do not want the percentage at each level.

I want my chart to look like this:

[image: chart]

I can calculate the percentages like this:

```
data %>%
  mutate(answer = recode_factor(answer, 
                                "Strongly Agree" = "Agree",
                                "Strongly Disagree" = "Disagree")) %>%
  group_by(items) %>%
  summarise(agree = sum(answer == 'Agree'), disagree = sum(answer == 'Disagree')) %>%
  mutate(percent_agree = agree / (agree + disagree)) %>%
  select(items, percent_agree)
```

But then I'm not sure how to match it back up with the correct statement & bar.  I tried joining the summarized percentages agree/strongly agree back to the original data before plotting it, and the using the `labels` options, but that didn't work as intended.

**How can I add the percentage agree / strongly agree as a label to my chart?**

---

```
data <- structure(list(items = c("Responds to longer-term changes in global market cycles", 
"Responds to longer-term changes in global market cycles", "Responds to longer-term changes in global market cycles", 
"Responds to longer-term changes in global market cycles", "Responds to longer-term changes in global market cycles", 
"Responds to longer-term changes in global market cycles", "Responds to longer-term changes in global market cycles", 
"Responds to longer-term changes in global market cycles", "Responds to longer-term changes in global market cycles", 
"Responds to longer-term changes in global market cycles", "Responds to longer-term changes in global market cycles", 
"Responds to longer-term changes in global market cycles", "Responds to longer-term changes in global market cycles", 
"Responds to longer-term changes in global market cycles", "Responds to longer-term changes in global market cycles", 
"Responds to longer-term changes in global market cycles", "Responds to longer-term changes in global market cycles", 
"Responds to longer-term changes in global market cycles", "Responds to longer-term changes in global market cycles", 
"Responds to longer-term changes in global market cycles", "Responds to longer-term changes in global market cycles", 
"Responds to longer-term changes in global market cycles", "Responds to longer-term changes in global market cycles", 
"Responds to longer-term changes in global market cycles", "Responds to longer-term changes in global market cycles", 
"Responds to longer-term changes in global market cycles", "Responds to longer-term changes in global market cycles", 
"Responds to longer-term changes in global market cycles", "Responds to longer-term changes in global market cycles", 
"Responds to longer-term changes in global market cycles", "Responds to longer-term changes in global market cycles", 
"Responds to longer-term changes in global market cycles", "Responds to longer-term changes in global market cycles", 
"Responds to longer-term changes in global market cycles", "Responds to longer-term changes in global market cycles", 
"Responds to longer-term changes in global market cycles", "Responds to longer-term changes in global market cycles", 
"Responds to longer-term changes in global market cycles", "Responds to longer-term changes in global market cycles", 
"Responds to longer-term changes in global market cycles", "Responds to longer-term changes in global market cycles", 
"Responds to longer-term changes in global market cycles", "Responds to longer-term changes in global market cycles", 
"Responds to longer-term changes in global market cycles", "Responds to longer-term changes in global market cycles", 
"Responds to longer-term changes in global market cycles", "Responds to longer-term changes in global market cycles", 
"Responds to longer-term changes in global market cycles", "Responds to longer-term changes in global market cycles", 
"Makes changes to respond to an existing business partners’ needs", 
"Makes changes to respond to an existing business partners’ needs", 
"Makes changes to respond to an existing business partners’ needs", 
"Makes changes to respond to an existing business partners’ needs", 
"Makes changes to respond to an existing business partners’ needs", 
"Makes changes to respond to an existing business partners’ needs", 
"Makes changes to respond to an existing business partners’ needs", 
"Makes changes to respond to an existing business partners’ needs", 
"Makes changes to respond to an existing business partners’ needs", 
"Makes changes to respond to an existing business partners’ needs", 
"Makes changes to respond to an existing business partners’ needs", 
"Makes changes to respond to an existing business partners’ needs", 
"Makes changes to respond to an existing business partners’ needs", 
"Makes changes to respond to an existing business partners’ needs", 
"Makes changes to respond to an existing business partners’ needs", 
"Makes changes to respond to an existing business partners’ needs", 
"Makes changes to respond to an existing business partners’ needs", 
"Makes changes to respond to an existing business partners’ needs", 
"Makes changes to respond to an existing business partners’ needs", 
"Makes changes to respond to an existing business partners’ needs", 
"Makes changes to respond to an existing business partners’ needs", 
"Makes changes to respond to an existing business partners’ needs", 
"Makes changes to respond to an existing business partners’ needs", 
"Makes changes to respond to an existing business partners’ needs", 
"Makes changes to respond to an existing business partners’ needs", 
"Makes changes to respond to an existing business partners’ needs", 
"Makes changes to respond to an existing business partners’ needs", 
"Makes changes to respond to an existing business partners’ needs", 
"Makes changes to respond to an existing business partners’ needs", 
"Makes changes to respond to an existing business partners’ needs", 
"Makes changes to respond to an existing business partners’ needs", 
"Makes changes to respond to an existing business partners’ needs", 
"Makes changes to respond to an existing business partners’ needs", 
"Makes changes to respond to an existing business partners’ needs", 
"Makes changes to respond to an existing business partners’ needs", 
"Makes changes to respond to an existing business partners’ needs", 
"Makes changes to respond to an existing business partners’ needs", 
"Makes changes to respond to an existing business partners’ needs", 
"Makes changes to respond to an existing business partners’ needs", 
"Makes changes to respond to an existing business partners’ needs", 
"Makes changes to respond to an existing business partners’ needs", 
"Makes changes to respond to an existing business partners’ needs", 
"Makes changes to respond to an existing business partners’ needs", 
"Makes changes to respond to an existing business partners’ needs", 
"Makes changes to respond to an existing business partners’ needs", 
"Makes changes to respond to an existing business partners’ needs", 
"Makes changes to respond to an existing business partners’ needs", 
"Makes changes to respond to an existing business partners’ needs", 
"Makes changes to respond to an existing business partners’ needs", 
"Responds to short-term market shifts", "Responds to short-term market shifts", 
"Responds to short-term market shifts", "Responds to short-term market shifts", 
"Responds to short-term market shifts", "Responds to short-term market shifts", 
"Responds to short-term market shifts", "Responds to short-term market shifts", 
"Responds to short-term market shifts", "Responds to short-term market shifts", 
"Responds to short-term market shifts", "Responds to short-term market shifts", 
"Responds to short-term market shifts", "Responds to short-term market shifts", 
"Responds to short-term market shifts", "Responds to short-term market shifts", 
"Responds to short-term market shifts", "Responds to short-term market shifts", 
"Responds to short-term market shifts", "Responds to short-term market shifts", 
"Responds to short-term market shifts", "Responds to short-term market shifts", 
"Responds to short-term market shifts", "Responds to short-term market shifts", 
"Responds to short-term market shifts", "Responds to short-term market shifts", 
"Responds to short-term market shifts", "Responds to short-term market shifts", 
"Responds to short-term market shifts", "Responds to short-term market shifts", 
"Responds to short-term market shifts", "Responds to short-term market shifts", 
"Responds to short-term market shifts", "Responds to short-term market shifts", 
"Responds to short-term market shifts", "Responds to short-term market shifts", 
"Responds to short-term market shifts", "Responds to short-term market shifts", 
"Responds to short-term market shifts", "Responds to short-term market shifts", 
"Responds to short-term market shifts", "Responds to short-term market shifts", 
"Responds to short-term market shifts", "Responds to short-term market shifts", 
"Responds to short-term market shifts", "Responds to short-term market shifts", 
"Responds to short-term market shifts", "Responds to short-term market shifts", 
"Responds to short-term market shifts", "Adopts new technologies", 
"Adopts new technologies", "Adopts new technologies", "Adopts new technologies", 
"Adopts new technologies", "Adopts new technologies", "Adopts new technologies", 
"Adopts new technologies", "Adopts new technologies", "Adopts new technologies", 
"Adopts new technologies", "Adopts new technologies", "Adopts new technologies", 
"Adopts new technologies", "Adopts new technologies", "Adopts new technologies", 
"Adopts new technologies", "Adopts new technologies", "Adopts new technologies", 
"Adopts new technologies", "Adopts new technologies", "Adopts new technologies", 
"Adopts new technologies", "Adopts new technologies", "Adopts new technologies", 
"Adopts new technologies", "Adopts new technologies", "Adopts new technologies", 
"Adopts new technologies", "Adopts new technologies", "Adopts new technologies", 
"Adopts new technologies", "Adopts new technologies", "Adopts new technologies", 
"Adopts new technologies", "Adopts new technologies", "Adopts new technologies", 
"Adopts new technologies", "Adopts new technologies", "Adopts new technologies", 
"Adopts new technologies", "Adopts new technologies", "Adopts new technologies", 
"Adopts new technologies", "Adopts new technologies", "Adopts new technologies", 
"Adopts new technologies", "Adopts new technologies", "Adopts new technologies"
), answer = structure(c(1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 
3L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 
1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
1L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("Strongly Agree", 
"Agree", "Disagree", "Strongly Disagree"), class = c("ordered", 
"factor"))), row.names = c(NA, -196L), class = "data.frame")
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A bit hacky, but gets the job done:

[image: 1]

#### Code

```
ggplot(data = d, aes(x = items, y = n)) +
    geom_col(aes(fill = answer), position = "fill") +
    coord_flip() +
    geom_label(aes(items, Inf,
                   label = ifelse(answer == "Agree", scales::percent(cumperc), NA),
                   hjust = 1,
                   vjust = 1)) +
    guides(fill = guide_legend(reverse = TRUE))
```

I exploited the factor level of "Agree" to plot its cumulative percentage. You can also see that your data is reshaped a bit to make working with it easier, but you can generally get the same results with wrangling the original dataset in runtime as well. It's just less pretty.

#### Data

```
d <- data %>% 
    # reshape into a more manageable format 
    group_by(items, answer) %>%
    summarize(n = n()) %>%
    ungroup() %>%
    # add cumulative percentages
    group_by(items) %>%
    mutate(cumperc = cumsum(n)/sum(n)) %>%
    ungroup() %>%
    # add line breaks to the items for aesthetic reasons
    mutate(items = gsub("to an", "to an\n", items),
           items = gsub("term changes", "term changes\n", items))

> head(d)
# A tibble: 6 x 4
  items                                    answer         n cumperc
  <chr>                                    <ord>      <int>   <dbl>
1 Adopts new technologies                  Strongly …     6   0.122
2 Adopts new technologies                  Agree         24   0.612
3 Adopts new technologies                  Disagree      19   1    
4 "Makes changes to respond to an\n exist… Strongly …     9   0.184
5 "Makes changes to respond to an\n exist… Agree         34   0.878
6 "Makes changes to respond to an\n exist… Disagree       6   1
```